# Explain this basic Kotlin function

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new to Java/Kotlin and am working through this [tutorial](https://www.varvet.com/blog/kotlin-with-volley/) to build an Android app with a widget that can query some JSON from a URL and render said results.

I am confused by the last code example:

```
val service = ServiceVolley()
val apiController = APIController(service)

val path = "example_endpoint"
val params = JSONObject()
params.put("email", "foo@email.com")
params.put("password", "barpass")

apiController.post(path, params) { response ->
    // Parse the result
}
```

> As usual in Kotlin, if the last parameter to a function is a function (and you're passing a lambda expression as the corresponding argument), you can specify it outside of parentheses, as we’ve done above — one of the small quirks I love about Kotlin.

In my widget code I have a helper function `updateAppWidget` in which I use the above code, and can sucessfully query the API, however I have ended up with the bulk of the code which was in the `updateAppWidget` function **inside** the `{ response -> // Parse the result }` block:

```
apiController.post(path,params) { response ->
    // Get 'bar' from the response which is {'foo':'bar'}
    val widgetText = response?.get(response.names().getString(0)).toString() 

    // Construct the RemoteViews object
    val views = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.statusr)
    views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text, widgetText)

    // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views)
}
```

Can someone explain the significance of the last 3 lines of the **first** code block, and tell me how I might write this to bring the logic up one level, and whether this is worth while?

The immediate problem I notice is that I can't reference widgetText outwith this block.

**EDIT for clarity**

I think I'm in over my head.  Further reading suggests that I'm passing a lambda by using `->`??? I guess what I really want to do is:

Get the call to `apiController.post` out of the widget code completely, so I have that now in a separate class:

```
class GetData {

    fun widget_text(){
        val service = ServiceVolley()
        val apiController = APIController(service)

        val path = "endpoint"
        val params = JSONObject()

        params.put("some", "data")

        apiController.post(path, params) { response ->
            val widgetText = response?.get(response.names().getString(0)).toString() 
        }
    }
}
```

Would like to be able to call something like `GetData.widget_text()` from within `updateAppWidget` but I'm back to my original problem: how do I make `widgetText` available outside `apiController.post(path,params) { response -> // Logic }}` and return this.

Comment: "the significance of the last 3 lines of the first code block": you create a new View to be displayed as homescreen widget (that's what a `RemoteViews` object is meant for), change the text and tell the AppWidgetManager to exchange the previously displayed Widget for the new one. One might of course introduce yet another function and put the three lines in there. Right now however I'm wondering whether it's a good idea to make the API call for every single appWidgetId (if the user decides to have five of your widgets side by side this means you'll do the API call five times)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and I will certainly consider this.  I've updated my question to be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning of the first last three lines: the data in *params* are passed to some type of backend (server).

```
apiController.post(path, params) { response ->
    val widgetText = response?.get(response.names().getString(0)).toString() 
    // Display the result in the App Widget
}
```

The request is executed asynchronously. This means, the code in the lambda expression will run after the response from the server comes in, while the UI of the app will remain clickable. The method which started the backend call, will have finished (if it had to wait until the response came in the UI could freeze).

A possible app structure using `GetData` as the class which manages the backend call:

```
class GetData {
    interface WidgetTextCallback {
        fun onTextLoaded(text: String)
    }

    companion object {
        fun widget_text(callback: WidgetTextCallback) {
            val service = ServiceVolley()
            val apiController = APIController(service)

            val path = "endpoint"
            val params = JSONObject()

            params.put("some", "data")

            apiController.post(path, params) { response ->
                val widgetText = response?.get(response.names().getString(0)).toString()
                callback.onTextLoaded(widgetText)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And use the interface to retrieve the widget text:

```
class NewAppWidget : AppWidgetProvider() {

    override fun onUpdate(context: Context, appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager, appWidgetIds: IntArray) {

        GetData.widget_text(object: GetData.WidgetTextCallback{
            override fun onTextLoaded(widgetText: String) {
                // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
                for (appWidgetId in appWidgetIds) {
                    updateAppWidget(context, widgetText, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId)
                }
            }
        })
    }

    companion object {

        internal fun updateAppWidget(context: Context, widgetText: String, appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager,
                                     appWidgetId: Int) {
            // Construct the RemoteViews object
            val views = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.new_app_widget)
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text, widgetText)

            // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your knowledgable answer, appologies on the delay in accepting this, I just got round to testing.  It's just a hobby project but it works!  Unfortunately I have another issue, so I've [spun up a repo](https://github.com/vulcan25/temperature-widget) and logged that there.  Perhaps at some point I'll get round to posting it here on SO. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

"bring this logic up one level" sounds like you want to handle the response somewhere else in your code. Why don't you just pass it to a handler function?

```
fun handleResponse(response: Type?) {
    // Parse the result
}

apiController.post(path, params) { response ->
    handleResponse(response)
}
```

or shorter:

```
apiController.post(path, params) { handleResponse(it) }
```

Comment: I think I'm looking for the opposite of this.  I want to return the response from `apiController.post` and assign it to another variable.